# disable "select" when the checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<div class="wcpa_form_item wcpa_type_checkbox-group wcpa_form_id_9547  eye_od_parent wcpa-col-2 wcpa_validate_field " id="wcpa-checkbox-group-1661439693440" data-type="checkbox-group">
        <div class="checkbox-group eye_od "data-validation="{"label":"checkbox-group-1661439693440"}">
              <div class="wcpa_checkbox">
                    <input name="checkbox-group-1661439693440[0]" id="checkbox-group-1661439693440_3_0"                                     value="occhio-destro" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
                    <label for="checkbox-group-1661439693440_3_0">
                    <span class="wcpa_check"></span>Occhio Destro</label>
              </div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="wcpa_form_item wcpa_type_select wcpa_form_id_9547  gradazione_os_od_parent wcpa-col-2 wcpa_validate_field " id="wcpa-select-1661440462701" data-type="select">
        <label for="select-1661440462700">gradazione OD<span class="required_ast">*</span></label>
        <div class="select">
            <select name="select-1661440462700" class="gradazione_os_od " required="required" data-validation="{"label":"gradazione OD","required":true,"requiredMessage":"Field is required"}">
                    <option value="">- scegli -</option>
                    <option value="-0.25">-0.25</option>
                    <option value="-0.50">-0.50</option>
                    <option value="-0.75">-0.75</option>
                    <option value="-1.00">-1.00</option>
                    <div class="select_arrow"></div>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

i'm just starting to work with javascript i'm trying them all but i can't modify this function, i need that when i deselect the "right eye" checkbox the select is disabled, unfortunately it's a wordpress plugin that allows you to do this operation only with show and hide but i need to disable, can someone help me please i'm really trying them all with null results, i'm looking for them online and all the ones i try are definitely not working i'm wrong something. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you could inject js code to your wordpress plugins but the basic code for this purpose goes like this. Make sure the id you are passing to the checkbox is unique.

```js
function check()
{
  if (document.getElementById('myCheckbox').checked) 
  {
      document.getElementById("mySelect").disabled = false;
  } else {
      document.getElementById("mySelect").disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wcpa_form_item wcpa_type_checkbox-group wcpa_form_id_9547  eye_od_parent wcpa-col-2 wcpa_validate_field " id="wcpa-checkbox-group-1661439693440" data-type="checkbox-group">
        <div class="checkbox-group eye_od "data-validation="{"label":"checkbox-group-1661439693440"}">
              <div class="wcpa_checkbox">
                    <input name="checkbox-group-1661439693440[0]" id="myCheckbox" value="occhio-destro" type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="check()">
                    <label for="checkbox-group-1661439693440_3_0">
                    <span class="wcpa_check"></span>Occhio Destro</label>
              </div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="wcpa_form_item wcpa_type_select wcpa_form_id_9547  gradazione_os_od_parent wcpa-col-2 wcpa_validate_field " id="wcpa-select-1661440462701" data-type="select">
        <label for="select-1661440462700">gradazione OD<span class="required_ast">*</span></label>
        <div class="select">
            <select id='mySelect' name="select-1661440462700" class="gradazione_os_od " required="required" data-validation="{"label":"gradazione OD","required":true,"requiredMessage":"Field is required"}">
                    <option value="">- scegli -</option>
                    <option value="-0.25">-0.25</option>
                    <option value="-0.50">-0.50</option>
                    <option value="-0.75">-0.75</option>
                    <option value="-1.00">-1.00</option>
                    <div class="select_arrow"></div>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks what you did is perfect but I have a problem being a plugin I cannot add the id or the onclick function to the html code in fact I'm going crazy for that because I tried as I showed it and seeing yours I understand why it didn't work

Comment: could I add the id to the divs and the onclick function with script? since I don't have access to the html code ...

Comment: Yes, you can use the id of a container div too. If jquery is available on your pages you can use something like this: `$('#container').find(':input');`

Comment: I'll try and in case I can publish how the thing ended

Comment: nothing ... I can't, could you help me to add the id to the "select" element and the function onclick = "check ()" in the input element with javascript? unfortunately I can't access the plugin html and it doesn't have a script area so I'm adding the scripts in the wordpress function.php page

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
  <head><title>disable "select" when the checkbox is unchecked</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wcpa_form_item wcpa_type_checkbox-group wcpa_form_id_9547  eye_od_parent wcpa-col-2 wcpa_validate_field " id="wcpa-checkbox-group-1661439693440" data-type="checkbox-group">
        <div class="checkbox-group eye_od "data-validation="{"label":"checkbox-group-1661439693440"}">
              <div class="wcpa_checkbox">
                      <input name="checkbox-group-1661439693440[0]" id="myCheckbox" value="occhio-destro" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
                      <label for="checkbox-group-1661439693440_3_0">
                      <span class="wcpa_check"></span>Occhio Destro</label>
                </div>
          </div>
   </div>

  <div class="wcpa_form_item wcpa_type_select wcpa_form_id_9547  gradazione_os_od_parent wcpa-col-2 wcpa_validate_field " id="wcpa-select-1661440462701" data-type="select">
          <label for="select-1661440462700">gradazione OD<span class="required_ast">*</span></label>
          <div class="select">
              <select id='mySelect' name="select-1661440462700" class="gradazione_os_od " required="required" data-validation="{"label":"gradazione OD","required":true,"requiredMessage":"Field is required"}">
                      <option value="">- scegli -</option>
                      <option value="-0.25">-0.25</option>
                      <option value="-0.50">-0.50</option>
                      <option value="-0.75">-0.75</option>
                      <option value="-1.00">-1.00</option>
                      <div class="select_arrow"></div>
              </select>
          </div>
  </div>
    <script>
    $('#myCheckbox').on('change', function(event){
        if($(this).prop("checked") == true)
        {
               $("#mySelect").prop('disabled',false);
        }
        else
        {
            $("#mySelect").prop('disabled',true);
        }
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This adds the ID's and event dynamically

```js
var checkbox = $("input[type=checkbox]");
$(checkbox).attr('id', 'myCheckbox');
var select = $(".gradazione_os_od")[0];
$(select).attr('id', 'mySelect');
console.log(select);


function check(){

  if ($('#myCheckbox').prop("checked"))
  {
      $("#mySelect").prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
      $("#mySelect").prop("disabled", true);
  }
}

$('#myCheckbox').on( "change", function() {
  check();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wcpa_form_item wcpa_type_checkbox-group wcpa_form_id_9547  eye_od_parent wcpa-col-2 wcpa_validate_field " id="wcpa-checkbox-group-1661439693440" data-type="checkbox-group">
        <div class="checkbox-group eye_od "data-validation="{"label":"checkbox-group-1661439693440"}">
              <div class="wcpa_checkbox">
                    <input name="checkbox-group-1661439693440[0]" id="checkbox-group-1661439693440_3_0"                                     value="occhio-destro" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
                    <label for="checkbox-group-1661439693440_3_0">
                    <span class="wcpa_check"></span>Occhio Destro</label>
              </div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="wcpa_form_item wcpa_type_select wcpa_form_id_9547  gradazione_os_od_parent wcpa-col-2 wcpa_validate_field " id="wcpa-select-1661440462701" data-type="select">
        <label for="select-1661440462700">gradazione OD<span class="required_ast">*</span></label>
        <div class="select">
            <select name="select-1661440462700" class="gradazione_os_od " required="required" data-validation="{"label":"gradazione OD","required":true,"requiredMessage":"Field is required"}">
                    <option value="">- scegli -</option>
                    <option value="-0.25">-0.25</option>
                    <option value="-0.50">-0.50</option>
                    <option value="-0.75">-0.75</option>
                    <option value="-1.00">-1.00</option>
                    <div class="select_arrow"></div>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

They are both valid solutions because I see that they work here but not on my page.
I answer the reflection on how I can insert javascript in a plugin ... Actually not directly in the plugin, but in the functions.php page in the child theme, through a script that I found online I can insert the javascript in the header or in the footer that communicates with the plugin, in fact I had found a script to try to enable the checkboxes inside the plugin when reloading the page and it worked so it can be done, but what you wrote for me does not take them, it does not assign me the id inside the elements and therefore the script does not work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).